# Excel RATE function in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

I tried to use RATE function in .NET CORE project.
There is a Visual Basic library I wanted to use but it does not work with .NET CORE. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.rate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Are there any other ways to use it or should I calculate it explicitly? How? I can't find any explanation of this function.

Comment: you can use tools such as ILSpy to see the source code of the Rate function in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597912/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-of-microsoft-visualbasic-financial-irr

Comment: Reversing source code and then using it might be legally risky. Fortunately Microsoft provides the source code for Rate under the MIT license here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/Microsoft.VisualBasic/runtime/msvbalib/Financial.vb#L718

Answer (score 4):

According to @omajid comment I transform official VB code to C#.
This is all you need to use Rate method without dependency on Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll which is lacking this method in .NET CORE.

```
private double Rate(double NPer, double Pmt, double PV, double FV = 0, DueDate Due = DueDate.EndOfPeriod, double Guess = 0.1)
{
    double dTemp;
    double dRate0;
    double dRate1;
    double dY0;
    double dY1;
    int I;

    // Check for error condition
    if (NPer <= 0.0)
        throw new ArgumentException("NPer must by greater than zero");

    dRate0 = Guess;
    dY0 = LEvalRate(dRate0, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
    if (dY0 > 0)
        dRate1 = (dRate0 / 2);
    else
        dRate1 = (dRate0 * 2);

    dY1 = LEvalRate(dRate1, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);

    for (I = 0; I <= 39; I++)
    {
        if (dY1 == dY0)
        {
            if (dRate1 > dRate0)
                dRate0 = dRate0 - cnL_IT_STEP;
            else
                dRate0 = dRate0 - cnL_IT_STEP * (-1);
            dY0 = LEvalRate(dRate0, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
            if (dY1 == dY0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Divide by zero");
        }

        dRate0 = dRate1 - (dRate1 - dRate0) * dY1 / (dY1 - dY0);

        // Secant method of generating next approximation
        dY0 = LEvalRate(dRate0, NPer, Pmt, PV, FV, Due);
        if (Math.Abs(dY0) < cnL_IT_EPSILON)
            return dRate0;

        dTemp = dY0;
        dY0 = dY1;
        dY1 = dTemp;
        dTemp = dRate0;
        dRate0 = dRate1;
        dRate1 = dTemp;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Can not calculate rate");
}

private double LEvalRate(double Rate, double NPer, double Pmt, double PV, double dFv, DueDate Due)
{
    double dTemp1;
    double dTemp2;
    double dTemp3;

    if (Rate == 0.0)
        return (PV + Pmt * NPer + dFv);
    else
    {
        dTemp3 = Rate + 1.0;
        // WARSI Using the exponent operator for pow(..) in C code of LEvalRate. Still got
        // to make sure that they (pow and ^) are same for all conditions
        dTemp1 = Math.Pow(dTemp3, NPer);

        if (Due != 0)
            dTemp2 = 1 + Rate;
        else
            dTemp2 = 1.0;
        return (PV * dTemp1 + Pmt * dTemp2 * (dTemp1 - 1) / Rate + dFv);
    }
}

private const double cnL_IT_STEP = 0.00001;
private const double cnL_IT_EPSILON = 0.0000001;

enum DueDate
{
    EndOfPeriod = 0,
    BegOfPeriod = 1
}
```